# new column with value from another one which name is in a third one in R

Tags: r

got that one I can't resolve.
Example dataset:

```
company <- c("compA","compB","compC")
compA <- c(1,2,3)
compB <- c(2,3,1)
compC <- c(3,1,2)
df <- data.frame(company,compA,compB,compC)
```

I want to create a new column with the value from the column which name is in the column "company" of the same line. the resulting extraction would be:

```
df$new <- c(1,3,2)
df
```

Comment: `df$new = diag(as.matrix(df[,2:4]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it set up, there's one row and one column for every company, and the rows and columns are in the same order. If that's your real dataset, then as others have said `diag(...)` is the solution (and you should select that answer).

If your real dataset has more than one instance of company (e.g., more than one row per company, then this is more general:

```
# using your df
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(i)df[i,as.character(df$company[i])])
# [1] 1 3 2

# more complex case
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
newdf <- data.frame(company=LETTERS[sample(1:3,10,replace=T)],
                    A = sample(1:3,10,replace=T), 
                    B=sample(1:5,10,replace=T), 
                    C=1:10)
head(newdf)
#   company A B C
# 1       A 1 5 1
# 2       B 1 2 2
# 3       B 3 4 3
# 4       C 2 1 4
# 5       A 3 2 5
# 6       C 2 2 6
sapply(1:nrow(newdf),function(i)newdf[i,as.character(newdf$company[i])])
#  [1] 1 2 4 4 3 6 7 2 5 3
```

Comment: great answer, you foresaw my intent - use this within a more complex case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: eddi's answer is probably better. It is more likely that you would have the dataframe to work with rather than the individual row vectors.

I am not sure if I understand your question, it is unclear from your description. But it seems you are asking for the diagonals of the data values since this would be the place where "name is in the column "company" of the same line". The following will do this:

```
df$new <- diag(matrix(c(compA,compB,compC), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
```

The `diag` function will return the diagonal of the matrix for you. So I first concatenated the three original vectors into one vector and then specified it to be wrapped into a matrix of three rows and three columns. Then I took the diagonal. The whole thing is then added to the dataframe.

Did that answer your question?

Comment: Yes more of a dataframe problem and the first answer seems more dynamic, but I could add the list and no. of vars for your code to work.